# RxJava: prevent an observable from emitting until data from another observable is emitted

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

The block of code below is designed to be offline-first. If data is emitted by the memory observable the local and remote observable will never fire. If data is not held in memory the local observable will attempt to read data from room database and if all else fails then the remote observable queries an API.

The remote source uses retrofit to send queries and returns a flowable which is then converted into an observable. Before the remote observable fires, however, I have another observable that returns location data needed by the query. In other words, the remote observable is dependent on the location observable. How do I can I use RxJava to prevent the remote observable from being called in the Concat operator until the location data is available?

```
locationObservable = locationSource.getLocationObservable();
memory = source.getSuggestionsFromMemory();
local = source.getSuggestionsFromDisk();


remote = source.getSuggestionsFromNetwork(parameters)
                    .skipUntil(locationObservable);

locationObservable.subscribe(
                    source -> parameters = ParamManager.queryParameters(
                                    source.getLatitude() + "," + source.getLongitude()),

                    error -> Log.println(Log.ERROR, TAG, error.getMessage()
                    )
            );

Observable.concat(memory,local, remote)
            .firstElement()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .toObservable()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

the remote observable:

```
public Observable<List<Venue>> getSuggestionsFromNetwork(HashMap<String, String> parameters){
    return remoteSource.getData(parameters).doOnNext(
            data -> {
                localSource.cacheDataToDisk(data);
                memorySource.cacheDataInMemory(data);
            });
}
```

remote source:

```
Observable<List<Venue>> getData(HashMap<String, String> params){
    return Flowable.zip(loadSearchVenues(params), loadTrendingVenues(params),
            loadRecommendedVenues(params), (search, trending, recommended) -> {

                generalVenues = search.getResponse().getSuggestions();
                trendingVenues = trending.getResponse().getSuggestions();
                recommendedVenues = recommended.getResponse().getSuggestions();

                allVenues.addAll(generalVenues);
                allVenues.addAll(trendingVenues);
                allVenues.addAll(recommendedVenues);

                return allVenues;
            }).toObservable();
}
```

error:

```
2019-11-15 09:18:08.703 29428-29491/com.example.suggest E/MemorySource: getData() called
2019-11-15 09:18:08.703 29428-29491/com.example.suggest E/LocalSource: getData() called
2019-11-15 09:18:08.767 29428-29428/com.example.suggest E/MainViewModel: Query map was null (parameter #3)
```

Comment: you asked the question really bad :) try to explain better what you want to achieve

Comment: Ok how is the question worded now

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to fetch the data from memory first and if it's not there from Database and if it fails there also fetch from API

Comment: so you want to read local data, if cache miss go online, always (aka = you don't care about stale content), correct?

Comment: yes, that is what the code does above. if there is not any data available the composite observables will call onComplete without emitting data. However, in order for the remote observable to query the API, it needs the devices' longitude and latitude.I was trying to figure out is there a way to prevent the remote observable from being called until location data is available.

Comment: @DanieleSegato I do care about stale data the location is updated every 5 miles

Comment: @DanieleSegato i really apologize. i added more code. the location observable above monitors location and updates the lat and lon passed to the remote source. but if a location is not produced in time or at all then the call to the network will return HTTP 400 bad request. what i am trying to achieve is to avoid sending the request at all if there is not a location available.

Comment: as far as the stale data i am aware that this is going to produce stale data i was going to try to fix this problem next.

Comment: i am new to reactive programming, so maybe i am getting the entire approach incorrect. i am open to any suggestions you have. even rewriting the code from a different approach

Comment: now your question is clear, I see someone answered you and you accepted the solution, good. Please take more time to explain the issue next time, I could have give you a solution days ago :)

Comment: i think the problem was my current capacity regarding reactive...i am new to it maybe you can address the concerns of staleness i don't know if it warrants a whole new post, but if i use the takeFirst() or first() operator and test for some flag would that work as far as delivering fresh content? you can add your answer to answers and i will vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wait until the next location emission you can do the following :

```java
locationObservable = locationSource.getLocationObservable();
memory = source.getSuggestionsFromMemory();
local = source.getSuggestionsFromDisk();
remote = locationObservable
           .map(source -> ParamManager.queryParameters(source.getLatitude() + "," 
                     + source.getLongitude()))
           .concatMap(params -> source.getSuggestionsFromNetwork(params));

Observable
  .concat(memory,local, remote)
  .firstElement()
...
```

But if you cannot you have to store the last location in a variable that can be used directly, something like :

```java
remote = Optional.ofNullable(getLastLocation())
           .map(Observable::just)
           .orElse(locationObservable)
           .map(source -> ParamManager.queryParameters(source.getLatitude() + "," 
                     + source.getLongitude()))
           .concatMap(params -> source.getSuggestionsFromNetwork(params));
```

And elsewhere :

```java
locationObservable.subscribe(location -> setLastLocation(location));
```

Comment: thank you for your help. was my question hard to understand? that was some of the feedback I've received

Comment: With the elements above no, it´s understandable. I upvote too